# How can I count the number of records in a .dat file

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, plsql

How can we  count the number of records in a .dat file including  header and tailer record .Written the code in plsql which fetches the records from cursor and writes  in a file using UTL_File.Any suggestions  to write the logic ...thanks in advance !!

Comment: What have you tried? Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your questions, which will give you better answers.

Comment: If you are in Unix, Simply use `wc  -l  yourfilename.dat` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Unix systems, and want the file count externally , you can use `wc -l yourfilename.dat`

If you need count inside `PL/SQL`, you can try something like this.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
    v_file    utl_file.file_type;
    v_line    VARCHAR2(4000); -- give proper size depending on your input.
    v_count   NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
    v_file := utl_file.fopen('YOUR_DIRECTORY',' yourfilename.dat','r');
    LOOP
        utl_file.get_line(v_file,v_line);
        v_count := v_count + 1;
    END LOOP;

    dbms_output.put_line('Total lines: '|| v_count);
END;
```